# How to update a dictionary value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a dictionary with range :

```
answered = dict.fromkeys(range(1,51))
```

output:

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: None, 13: None, 14: None, 15: None, 16: None, 17: None, 18: None, 19: None, 20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None, 27: None, 28: None, 29: None, 30: None, 31: None, 32: None, 33: None, 34: None, 35: None, 36: None, 37: None, 38: None, 39: None, 40: None, 41: None, 42: None, 43: None, 44: None, 45: None, 46: None, 47: None, 48: None, 49: None, 50: None}
```

and I've tried to update the values like this:

```
answered[1] = sent_answer #sent_answer -> some text
```

but what I get is:

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, ..... ,49: None, 50: None, '1': 'I- III - II - IV'}
```

it's adding a new dict item and the key is str so instead I want it to update the value of the specified key.

Comment: your code is working for me. I don't see any problem when I try to run it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do the job neatly, better use `update` method of the dictionary like below:

```
my_dict = {1:"a value", 2:"another value"}
my_dict.update({1:"your value"})
```

also, from Python 3.10 on you can do the following:

```
my_dict |= {1:"your value"}
```

still, there is more:

```
my_dict = {**my_dict, 1:"your value"}
```

and you will get the following result:

```
{1:"your value", 2:"another value"}
```

note that you can add the current key value or new ones. In general, it's an **upsert** kind of operation.

Comment: "If you want to make sure it will do the job 100%, better use update" Can you explain exactly how `d.update({1: X})` does something different than `d[1] = X`? Why does the later not do the job 100% in your mind?

Comment: You are so picky mate :)). Anyway, if you use an API like `update` it's more stable for future changes also it's more readable cause you know it's an update to an existing state.

Comment: "it's more stable for future changes " So you are implying that `d[1] = X` might change in the future? Interesting... Is this backed by any facts or just your feeling? As for "it is more reable",  this is highly subjective and `d[1] = X` seems as readable to me as `update` and shorter for just one key+value change. You also didn't explain why you imply that the non update version does not do the job "100%" while update does. Can you give an example when it does not do the job?

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope you get a better sleep after this.

Comment: In my sleep I dream of people giving facts and not feelings about why one solution is "neat" and not the other. Plus in fact really solving the issue at hand, because it is unclear what OP really had as a problem, but it was certainly not because using `d[1] = X` and as such using `update` in his case would have produced the exact same result.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have same type of the key you are trying to update. If it was a string in the dict, then when updating, use a string. If you do otherwise, python will see it as a different key and add one.

```
answers = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
answers[1] = 'some text'
print(answers)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'some text', 2: None, 3: None}
```

But if you use different type, then a new key is added.

```
answers['2'] = 'new text'
print(answers)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'some text', 2: None, 3: None, '2': 'new text'}
```

Keys are also case sensitive when they are string.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing as *@NicolasGuruphat* answer.

I believe the issue you have is one this part

> and I've tried to update the values like this:
>
> ````py
> answered[1] = sent_answer #sent_answer -> some text```
> ````

I think if you went back to your code you'll find `answered["1"]` instead of `answered[1]`

Comment: but I want to update the value not to add a new one

Comment: I know, but in your code you don't replace you add. that's why you gotta use answered[1] instead of answered["1"] because the last one adds